# Row color distortion in Datatable on some events

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

[screen shot of table row colors getting distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06330.jpg)

We are facing table row color distortion issue in our application whenever we perform any kind of event like click, scroll or resize.
We got a solution for this as below,

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
var table = $('#our-table').DataTable();
table.columns.adjust().draw();
});
```

We are using properties of datatable like resizeWidth, paginationType, responsive etc.

However this operation has to be done whenever an event occurs. We are looking for better solution so that the datatable need not be adjusted everytime an event occurs.

The below CSS is getting applied to the table

```
table {
width: 100%;
}

.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable {
margin: 0px 0px;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer {
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer {
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}
table {
background-color: transparent;
}

for table body

tbody {
display: table-row-group;
}
.dataTables_wrapper table, .dataTables_wrapper th, .dataTables_wrapper td {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.dataTable {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: don't know exactly what's wrong. But see this link https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/events.html
they are using some extra css for events.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what it's suppose to be like?

Comment: I have already attached the screen shot here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/06330.jpg

Comment: can you add a runnable code snippet or jsfiddle?